# Gradle 3.4 app/libs, File not found: app/libs (Is a directory)

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

In building the release version of my app, it works on gradle 3.3.2 but upgrading to 3.4.0 I get the above error. If I comment out -libraryjars libs in proguard-rules.pro everything works. It appears -libraryjars no longer accepts a directory and needs specific file paths. The documentation still says it should take a directory.

Am I missing something to make it work with a directory path?

Comment: Can you post relevant parts of your `build.gradle`?

Comment: I had this issue as well and I ended up referring to this gradle release notes https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#behavior_changes
for me, the issue is fixed after I disable r8

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following answer to solve this issue:

Add these lines in your `gradle.properties` file

```
# Disables R8 for Android Library modules only.
android.enableR8.libraries = false
# Disables R8 for all modules.
android.enableR8 = false
```

Next, remove the following line from your proguard rules if it exists

```
-libraryjars libs
```